# How can I run child Docker image command before parent image command

Tags: maven, docker, jenkins

I have a Jenkins parent image, where I added maven in a child image. For Maven proxy, I need to change setting.xml to copy data from environment variables.

In the child image, I can add the shell script to change settings.xml and then run the Entry point from Jenkins parent image. But then I have to keep track of any changes in the parent Jenkins image.

Is there a way in Docker to refer to parent cmd/entrypoint or prepend some command to parent cmd directly?

Comment: There's `depends_on`, where you can define dependencies for your services ([see the docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#dependson)). So you can define an ordering -- assumed that you use docker-compose

Comment: @n2o, thanks but I am not using compose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your maven image is just a layer above the jenkins one: you can see all the files/scripts installed by the jenkins parent image.

If you look at the Dockerfile of the parent image, you will find its cmd/entrypoint and can configure it in your maven Dockerfile

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to avoid copying commands from Jenkins as I didn't understand "tini". I ended up doing this.